# How to write the query for interactive grid based on the select list in Oracle Apex

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I have a drop down select list (`P2_ROLE`). I want to generate the interactive grid based on the value that I select from the drop down.

I am trying to do that but the query is not returning any result in the grid. However, if I query it in the database, it returns me the result.

It looks like that it is not substituting the value from the dropdown into the IG query. But If I hard code the value, it gives me the results.

[dropdown_IG issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CbwhA.png)

I also tried returning the value selected from the dropdown in the item : `P2_SELECT_LIST_VALUE` and then using it in the query. But it also doesn't work.

The query that I have used for my Interactive grid is :

```
  Select USER_NAME
  From WF_USER_ROLES
  Where ROLE_NAME = :P2_SELECT_LIST_VALUE ;  --using the value from new item
```

or

```
  Select USER_NAME
  From WF_USER_ROLES
  Where ROLE_NAME = :P2_ROLE;  -- using the value directly from Dropdown
```

After selecting the value in the dropdown, I am refreshing the IG region using dynamic action on change select list. But that also doesn't help. How can I do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select list returns two values: *display* and *return*. Its form is, for example,

```
select dname  disp_val,
       deptno ret_val
from dept;
```

Its *return value* is then used in interactive grid's query.

Also, in order to be able to use select list's value, it has to be stored in session state; if it is not, query won't work. The simplest option is to *submit* the page, and you can do that by setting that item's **Page action on selection** property to "Submit page". Doing so, your IG query:

```
Select USER_NAME
From WF_USER_ROLES
Where ROLE_NAME = :P2_ROLE
```

should work OK. If it still does not, create an example on apex.oracle.com, provide credentials so that we could have a look at what you did.

Comment: Thank a lot ! That works perfectly. I was missing on setting the 'Page action on Selection property' to "Submit PAge" . After setting it, it is working perfectly !